# How to combine createStackNavigator createDrawerNavigator in latest version of react navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-drawer, react-navigation-v5

**In the latest version of react-navigation v5 how to combine createStackNavigator with createDrawerNavigator**

This is my main navigator file.

```
import InitialScreen from '@InitialScreen'
import SignIn from '@SignIn'
import Home from '@Home'
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
class NavigationStack extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
            <Stack.Screen name="InitialScreen" component={InitialScreen} options={{ headerShown: false }}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SignIn} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
            <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
           </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
export default NavigationStack;
```

**In my Home component I have bottom-tabs**

```
 import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
 import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
 const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
  class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
   <Tab.Navigator>
     <Tab.Screen
        name="Documents"
        component={Images}
        options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'Images',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <Image source={Images.iconDocuments}/>
          ),
        }}
        />
      <Tab.Screen
         name="Profile"
         component={Profile}
         options={{
          tabBarLabel: 'IRROP',
          tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
            <Image source={Images.iconImages}/>
          ),
       }}
       />
      </Tab.Navigator>
     )
    }
  }
 export default Home;
```

**I want to include Drawer Navigation in Stack Navigation How can I do it in  react-navigation v5**